# Issues with MDX query - unwanted output

Tags: sql, excel, mdx

I'm trying to pull some data from a cube I use in business which has millions of data in it. I am using MDX, which I'm very new to, and I'm trying to replicate the output of one of my pivot tables. I created the query and it seems like everything is in the right place, however the output seems to be inverted (rows on columns and columns on rows, please see pictures for details) And for some reason I can't figure out how to fix it.

This image shows both the desired output and the actual output:
This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Dem 
Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}), 
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[TheDate].[Fiscal Year].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})), 
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[TheDate].[Quarter].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[TheDate].[Month].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Running].[Business].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Reporting].[segment].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}))
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME 
ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
(SELECT 
({[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductX],
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductY], 
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductZ],
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductA],
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductB], 
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductC],
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductD],
{[Reporting].[segment].&[Online telecom], 
[Reporting].[segment].&[Online shop],    
[Reporting].[segment].&[ground sales], 
[Reporting].[segment].&[Retail],   
[Reporting].[segment].&[third party]})
ON COLUMNS

FROM [SalesCube])

WHERE 
([Reporting.[UPSegment].&[1stDivision],
[Measures].[BusinessRevenue]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE,
FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

the reason I want the output is so I can import the data into power bi and manipulate to add adhoc measures needed to run my business.
ANY HELP I CAN GET WILL BE MUCH APPRECIATED =) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the query below

```
SELECT NON EMPTY CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(CrossJoin(Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Dem 
Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}), 
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[TheDate].[Fiscal Year].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})), 
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[TheDate].[Quarter].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[TheDate].[Month].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Running].[Business].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)})),
Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Reporting].[segment].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}))
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME 
ON rows,
[Measures].[BusinessRevenue] on columns

FROM 
(SELECT 
({[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductX],
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductY], 
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductZ],
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductA],
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductB], 
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductC],
[Dem Product].[Dem Product Hierarchy].[Dem allProducts].&[ProductD],
{[Reporting].[segment].&[Online telecom], 
[Reporting].[segment].&[Online shop],    
[Reporting].[segment].&[ground sales], 
[Reporting].[segment].&[Retail],   
[Reporting].[segment].&[third party]})
ON COLUMNS

FROM [SalesCube])

WHERE 
([Reporting.[UPSegment].&[1stDivision]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE,
FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

Comment: Thanks @mozarub! i got the output I was looking for in ssms. However when I use this code and write in powerbi to get the data set in there, for some reason it doesn't give me a similar output. when I run it in PBI each hierarchy has 2 columns: 1 ending with [parent_unique_name] and 1 ending with [hierarchy_unique_name] with either blank cells all the way down or "all" cells(i.e can't filter by fy19, fy20, etc but rather only by blanks or "[TheDate].[Fiscal Year].[All]" for parent and [TheDate].[Fiscal Year] for hierarchy). same for all hierarchies. Measures seem OK otherwise. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it solves your problem you should mark it as an answer. Secondly PBi has its formating things. try removeing "DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME "

Comment: Thanks, MoazRub. Very new to this forum as well but I have checked it as an answer =). I will try removing what you suggested and see if it works in PBi. thank you!